# Will a potted pomegranate tree grow in Zone 6?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, containers, overwintering, pomegranate

Is it possible to grow a potted pomegranate tree in southern Ohio? I'm in zone 6, which means the lowest temperatures in the winter are generally in the range of −5 °F (−20.6 °C). I have a shed, but not a garage to move it inside during the winter. My backyard faces West and gets full sun.

Will it survive the winter? If so, will it produce fruit eventually?

Comment: Hi Kristen! Welcome to the site! Do you already have the tree, or did you want to know if it will grow in your area before buying it? If you have it, do you know the variety? How old is it? Has it ever fruited? If not, is there one you'd prefer? I haven't grown any, but according to my research hardiness varies by variety, and there are some which would likely work for you. Let us know!

Comment: I do not have a plant yet. It's just something I'm thinking about for next summer!

Answer (score 1):

The [Clemson University Extension recommends several cold-hardy cultivars](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/plants/vegetables/tree_fruits_nuts/hgic1359.html) (though they don't specify what zone!):

> #### Compact Cultivars (Less Than 6 Feet Tall)
>
> - ‘State Fair’ will grow to about 5 feet tall and produces many dwarf
>     fruits (less than 2 inches in diameter). This selection is very cold
>     hardy and flowers profusely.
> - ‘Nana’ is the most dwarf variety. It
>     grows 2 to 3 feet tall with red-orange, single flowers followed by
>     small fruit. More cold hardy than others of the species.
>
> #### Russian Series (High Cold Tolerance)
>
> While there are 19 cultivars in this group, often listed by number,
>   the following are becoming more available from nurseries.
>
> - ‘Afganski’ (R26) produces medium-sized fruit with sweet-tart flavor.
>     Dark red arils.
> - ‘Salavatski’ (R8) is an excellent producer of large
>     fruit whose light red arils yield a fruity, sweet-tart juice.
>     Semi-soft, edible seeds. Excellent juicing variety.
> - ‘Surh-Anor’ (R33)
>     is a semi-dwarf bush type (up to 10 feet) with very sweet juice. Arils
>     are a clear, pale red.

A [Texas A&M publication](http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/fruit-nut/files/2015/04/pomegranates_2015.pdf) suggests varieties that may be hardy down to Zone 7:

> Studies are under way on varieties that survive typical winters in north
>   central Texas and produce fruit; these include Al-sirin-nar, Salavatski,
>   and Russian 18.